# websocket gets blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I am trying to run a websocket example having java code in one port(8080) and java script code in another port(8080)

problem : when i deploy client and server on same port it works properly but when client app.js is on different port than server port it throws error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8091/websocket-example/info?t=1601539296700' from
> origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

java configuration file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/websocket-example")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

contoller file

```
@Controller
public class ChattingController {


    @MessageMapping("/user")
    @SendTo("/topic/user")
    public UserResponse getUser(User user) {

        return new UserResponse("Hi " + user.getName());
    }
}
```

app.js

```
var stompClient = null;

function setConnected(connected) {
    $("#connect").prop("disabled", connected);
    $("#disconnect").prop("disabled", !connected);
    if (connected) {
        $("#conversation").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#conversation").hide();
    }
    $("#userinfo").html("");
}

function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8091/websocket-example');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/user', function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
}

function disconnect() {
    if (stompClient !== null) {
        stompClient.disconnect();
    }
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Disconnected");
}

function sendName() {
    stompClient.send("/app/user", {}, JSON.stringify({'name': $("#name").val()}));
}

function showGreeting(message) {
    $("#userinfo").append("<tr><td>" + message + "</td></tr>");
}

$(function () {
    $("form").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $( "#connect" ).click(function() { connect(); });
    $( "#disconnect" ).click(function() { disconnect(); });
    $( "#send" ).click(function() { sendName(); });
});
```

springsecurity file

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer, WebMvcRegistrations {
    
    private static final String EVERYTHING = "/**";

    @Bean
    public SuperInterceptor superInterceptor() {
        return new SuperInterceptor();
    } 
    
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        
        List<String> paths =  new ArrayList<String>();
        paths.add("/login");
        paths.add("/user/register");
        registry.addInterceptor(superInterceptor()).addPathPatterns(EVERYTHING).excludePathPatterns(paths);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity.cors();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

ps: i am new to websocket sorry if this is a naive issue

Comment: Are you using Spring-Security as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure it with Spring Security then try this, it might helps you. Add it in the WebSecurityConfig file of Spring Security.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    }
```

OR

If you are just configure the Spring MVC then try this:

```
        @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST","PUT", "DELETE");


                }
            };
        }
```